# SQL Server Join temp tables and Pivot

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with data

**TABLE 1**:
Counts of service for weekdays

```
    -------------------------------------------------------
    | Day of Wk| Sun | Mon | Tue |  Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat |
    |  1       |  50 |  0  |   0 |   0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
    |  2       |  0  | 75  |   0 |   0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
    |  3       |  0  | 0   |  89 |   0  |  0  |  0  |  0  |
```

**TABLE 2**:
Table 2 with Production Totals by for selected services (Prod A - C) by weekday

```
    -------------------------------------------------------
    | Day of Wk| Date        | Prod_A | Prod_B |  Prod_C | 
    |  1       |  2015-01-01 | 4000   |  8000  |   9000  |
    |  2       |  2015-01-14 | 3000   |  7000  |   8000  |  
    |  3       |  2015-01-05 | 2000   |  2000  |   5000  |
```

I need a query to produce this table:

Service counts of Weekdays = Total Service counts of table 1 in a column

```
    -------------------------------------------------------
    | Day of Wk | Service_Count | Prod_A | Prod_B |  Prod_C | 
    |  Sun      |  50           | 4000   |  8000  |   9000  |
    |  Mon      |  75           | 3000   |  7000  |   8000  |  
    |  Tue      |  89           | 2000   |  2000  |   5000  |
```

I am pretty new to pivoting and not sure if pivot is way to go for this or not.

In this recordset the `Day of Wk` column represents the day of the week, i.e. 1=Sunday

Comment: Your `Prod_A` data appears to have changed.

Comment: your expected output is misleading with Table 2 content.

Comment: Looks like a bad table design but anyway...based on that sample data simply join on `Day of Wk` to get a single recordset of three rows. Column `Service_Count` is simply `Sun+Mon_Tue+Wed+Thu+Fri+Sat`. But I bet the real data is more complicated than that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen good catch, I corrected the figures.

Comment: Table 1 was derived using sum counts from a table similar to Table 2. The production figures in table 2 are derived from Services performed and pulling their Amount_totals into the columns. There are also  date columns such as "day of week" , "week" , "Quarter" .. Basically I want to produce the days of week as rows.. I dont know if table 2 is enough to produce the table I need? @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Normal join between two tables is not helping you is it?.  Or is there any catch which I m missing :/

Comment: Does the number in `Day of Week` signify anything? Does 1=Sun? Or do we need to derive it from the date? Your dataset is ambiguous - what meaning does the column `Day of Week` have? Is it just a meaningless number?

Comment: why do you need piVot here didn't understand...simple Inner join should suffice...

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes my apoligies for not stating that earlier , Days of week (1-7)signify the days of the week starting from Sunday.

Comment: WIll the values 1-7 repeat?. In the full dataset could you have multiple records with the value 7?

Comment: @Avi thanks for your query that shaped it up. I also tried an inner join on day of week and it worked too! thanks for your help everyone                 `Select t1.dow,t2.prod_a,t2.prod_b,t2.prod_c from #TEMP2 t2
JOIN #TEMP1 t1
ON t1.dow = t2.dow`

Comment: @Swazzy cheers. If my answer helped you please accept the answer by upvote.

Comment: @avi I still need some rep so if you could add to mine i will return the favor. Btw thanks so much again :)

Comment: @Swazzy done have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but looks simple to me.Sorry if I have not understood your question.

```
select t1.days_of_Week,(t1.sun+t1.mon+t1.tue+t1.wed+t1.thr+t1.fri+t1.sat) 
Service_Count, t2.Prod_A,t2.Prod_B,t2.Prod_C 
from Table1 t1,Table2 t2 
where t1.days_of_week = t2.days_of_Week;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to produce what you shared then the following query should do the job... @Swazzy

```
SELECT unpiv.[Day] AS Days_of_Week, unpiv.[Count] AS Service_Count,t2.Prod_A,t2.Prod_B,t2.Prod_C
FROM ( SELECT t.* FROM Table1 t) d
    UNPIVOT
    (
      [Count]
      for [Day] in (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thurs, Fri)
    ) unpiv 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Days_of_week = unpiv.days_of_week
WHERE unpiv.[Count] > 0
```